# Trigger/Constraints for deleting table hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012, cascading-deletes

I have the following table structure which stores some results of my application. Each hierarchy level has a data row attached which again consists of multiple values. A data row is exclusively assigned to a single table of the hierarchy tables, not many in parallel. My goal is to delete the `Parent` including all hierarchy levels, the data and values.

[image: Hierarchical Structure]

My first attempt was to add ON DELETE CASCADE constraints everywhere but `ON DELETE CASCADE` does not work with a *diamond* structure. It results in:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Data_Hierarchy2' on table 'Data' may cause cycles or cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other KEY constraints.
```

Then my second attempt was to remove the cascade constraint on the Data table and add a `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger to Hierarchy 1-3 which deletes the Data entries before the own rows. But also there the SQL Server complains that you cannot add such a trigger due to the `ON DELETE CASCADE` which is there for the hierarchy nesting.

```
Cannot create INSTEAD OF DELETE or INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER 'TR_Hierarchy1_Delete' on table 'dbo.Hierarchy'. This is  because the table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE.
```

My last plan would be to remove all `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraints and delete the whole tree manually in a trigger. But this is quite a challenge do it in an optimized fashion.

- What is really the best solution for this job? Iterating over the rows using cursors? (possibly slow due to iteration)
- Use combined joins to select the affected rows for every individual table? (possibly slow due to redundant joining the whole hierarchy)
- Or does somebody know a trick how to delete over multiple tables using a result set?

Comment: Why is cascade delete a challenge? Why do you think the triggers will be better optimized?

Comment: Removing the `ON DELETE CASCADE` and to the whole cascade deleting manually is a challenge to do it optimized. Like I mentioned in the bullet points: One way would be to have invidvidual 10 delete queries. One for each table joining always from top (Parent) to the bottom (Values) of the overall hierarchy. Another way would be via to iterate through the hierarchy via cursors.

Comment: Use `no action` on some of the branches of your delete cycle and it should work.

Comment: Then I still have to delete those left-over branches manually, preferrable by trigger. But this way SQL Server will complain that you cannot have a `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger due to the `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the Hierarchy tables. An `AFTER` trigger will not work because deleting the Hierarchy row would cause a FK violation which will cause the trigger not to be fired.

Comment: No, the other side of the cycle will take care of that. You will have cascade from Hierarchy1 to Data and no action from Hierarchy2/3 to Data.

Comment: Okay, now I unterstand and it seems my description was not clear enough. As shown in the diagram: All hierarchy levels have exactly 1 data entry assigned, but not the same one. If I'd only cascade from Hierarchy 1, the data rows related to Hierarchy 2 and 3 would remain.